# hibernate inheritance for an online library/shop design implementation choice

Tags: java, hibernate, table-per-subclass

I wish to implement an online library in hibernate. Here is my sql sschema:

[image: sql schema]

Between Book and Programming book I am thinking of using hibernate inheritance of type table per subclass joined. I designed the sql schema this way because I don't see the point of having the same columns duplicate in 10 tables. Maybe I need to add one more common column, I don't want to do it in 10 tables. But this means that whenever a Book is needed somewhere, a huge join would be made between all the subtables ( I have only 2, but I could have 50 book types!!! ). The same stuff applies if for example I would have had an online shop: I would have had Product, Tv, Laptop, Phone, etc...).

What design can help me avoid this behaviour?

My thoughts are:

- I could duplicate all the columns in all the subtables, and thus, don't use inheritance at all, treat them like different entities. The only thing here is that I will have to tie every specific book table of other tables ( authors, etc )
- I could avoid using inheritance, keep the current sql schema but use unidirectional association ( a ProgrammingBook has a Book, etc )

What option do you guys recommend?

Kind regards,

Comment: "The only thing here is that I will have to tie every specific book table of other tables ( authors, etc )" Can you detail please ? :)

Comment: As you can see right now, a ProgrammingBook relation to authors is through Book. If I would duplicate the columns in each table, then ProgrammingBook should be tied to authors, etc, then PsychologyBook need to have relations with authors, etc, and the same for each book

Comment: It was what I though but I would be sure. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From experience, when using inheritance with Hibernate, you should prefer the Table per Hierarchy point of view, with a discriminator.

Here's a thread that could help you pick an answer : [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

Comment: I agree with you, from performance point of view, but what would mean to put all products in the same table and de-normalizing the sql schema.

Comment: It wouldn't be a very expensive operation, as you will be able to quickly get your data